# Proxy tether android >> Firefox works, ssh/wget/apt do not. Is this a tcp/http issue?

Tags: android, http, ubuntu, tcp, kde-plasma

I am able to get a manual proxy set up in firefox using android-sdk adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080 to the proxoid app, but for some reason none of my command line utilities (wget,ssh,apt) recognize this manual proxy.

For instance, $bash: ssh username@host.org 
returns >>> ssh: Could not resolve hostname host.org: Name or service not known

I tried "manual change proxy settings" in the kde proxy module to run over localhost:8080, but still commands like wget, ssh, etc., do not recognize the manual proxy.  The ssh error is the same, but I can still browse the internet with firefox no problem!

Then I tried creating an .ssh/config with Host * and ProxyCommand corkscrew localhost 8080 %h %p as [suggested here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-use-ssh-via-http-proxy-using-corkscrew-in-ubuntu.html).  Still no luck.

Any KDE guru's know what I might be doing wrong?  Is this at all related to the fact that I am invoking a tcp connection between my laptop and my android (over adb) while corkscrew and KDE Proxy normally operate over http connections to remote proxies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates a problem with DNS.  You need to get DNS working on the device too, or use IP addresses instead of host names.

Comment: i do not agree - why would DNS be the problem if i am able to browse without issue in firefox?

Comment: Because then the HTTP proxy resolves the addresses, not your device. For kicks, try ssh with the IP address of the destination as a simple validation test.

Answer (score 1):

- [Proxoid](http://code.google.com/p/proxoid/) is an [HTTP proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy), not an SSH proxy. So, the only apps that will work correctly are those that speak HTTP.
- To get command-line programs (like [wget](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) or [apt](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)) to work correctly, try setting the "[http_proxy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1575)" environment variable, thus: `$ export http_proxy=localhost:8080`.

Comment: I just set HTTP_PROXY="127.0.0.1:8080" and FTP_PROXY="127.0.0.1:8080".  I tried both with and without quotes, updated with KDE's "using preset proxy environment variables", source /etc/environment, even rebooted KDE, and still no luck ...

Comment: The environment variable to set is "http_proxy", in all lower case.

Comment: /etc/environment is not case sensitive; there are docs online that say HTTP_PROXY, and from experience you can set path or PATH in a .bashrc or /etc/environment

Comment: KDE's "using preset proxy environment variables" autodetect did recognize the HTTP_PROXY and FTP_PROXY, so it seems like that is not the issue ... weird ...

Comment: also tried http_proxy="tcp:8080" for completeness --> did not work (not sure why this would have worked, anyways) ... thank you for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

My desperate solution later that night (fwiw): root your phone.  [Tetherbot](http://graha.ms/androidproxy/)  handles both socks and ssh proxies; it worked wonders for me, although it is a little unstable (needed to reboot multiple times, root a second time, etc).

Based on the google code page for proxoid, gnome users can get this a full proxy pretty easily -- I have not had any such luck with kde.  If anyone out there gets this working with kde, ping me and I will accept your answer!